# script is executed only if awk didn't find any number greater than

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this command:

`program script.sh >/dev/null 2>&1 &`

The "program" execute "script.sh" only if one condition from the "program" are true. 
And I want to add another condition in the "script.sh" with awk or sed.
for example :

`if in the output of "program" is only one number greather than 60
do not send email
if not 
send email`

the output of the program is something like this :
`program.log`

`peak: -5.19dB (not silent)
peak: -74.75dB (X seconds of silence)
**SILENCE**
59 seconds left in grace period.`

And I don't want to write the output from "program" on disk (only if this is possible)

Thanks!

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: I think the problem is really in (execute_)script.sh.... we need you to open that script up... as I think "silentjack" is simply pushing its output to that script.  The magic that controls printing your email happens inside there & it is inside there that we need to add the check.

Comment: @Snowman -- It would be helpful to us to keep your original question, then also copy a sanitized version of the contents of execute_script.sh -- because your question really involves "I have this program that is triggering events that are sent to a script, but I need to save state and do something special... What direction should I go in to fix this?"

Answer (score 1):

I think that inside your `script.sh` you need a test prior to mailing...

```
awk -F '[ (]+' '$7 > 90 { exit 1 }'
```

The answer likely involves using named pipes, tee + process substitution, tee + FD's or ...

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28503/how-can-i-send-stdout-to-multiple-commands

Comment: maybe is another way. I'll try to explain. silentjack execute desire comand when SILENCE is triggered. silentjack count the seconds and then execute. After that, have a grace period, count again and execute if is still silence.but in grace period did't make any detection.And I cannot put a long grace period.I want to avoid to send mail again and again. I use msmtp and mutt to send mail via google account. msmtp write a log starting with date and time when send email. maybe is more simple to count this ...i don't know. @ Michael Black : thank you!

Comment: Whew! Snowman, you are really having fun!  I think you need to save some state in a file from each silentjack event for subsequent executions.  You can use a mix of AWK and shell for this, or just use AWK (I would think skipjack will take any simple filter executable as its callback script).

Comment: @Ed -- I was trying this out on the command line and at one time the version with strtonum() worked... so I just copied that version as the draft answer... I updated it just now to pull the strtonum() out.